# SignalR Hub - get mapped in a third-party plugin

Tags: iis, signalr

I need to create an extension as a third-party utilizing SignalR and the built-in features of the software. First, I read all the questions and answers on Stackoverflow and summed up like this (I'm not sure, if all are right):

- A second invokation of app.MapSignalR() (where app is from type IAppBuilder) is useless, because the javascript proxy is already built and cached
- The invokation need to happen before the RouteTables are set.
- As far as I know MapSignalR searches for Classes that derives from Hub in all loaded assemblies, and instantiate them on demand.

The software mentioned before initiates the application as an HTTPModule of IIS, and somewhere (blackbox for me) the mapping of hubs happen. I tried to load my assembly with my Hubs beforehand, thus my assembly is available also for the registration of hubs, although as I try to access it via $.connection.adminHub (see the example below), I fail.

Where is the mistake in my approach?

**EDIT 1** 
(17. 07. 2017)

Goal of AdminHub: provide a server endpoint for specific clients in the application to invoke the client side function which refreshes the browser (with forcing to reload without cache). 
I managed to build a working standalone ASP.NET Application:

**AdminHub.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace HelloSignalR
{
   public class AdminHub : Hub
   {
      Clients.All.refresh();
   }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin App of SignalR</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Admin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Admin Page for Reload all clients</h1>
    <button id="refreshButton">Refresh without cache</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(HelloSignalR.Startup))]

namespace HelloSignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

**Admin.js**

```
(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Thereby browsers reload pretty quickly,
        // output an alert for the user, that he gets noticed about refresh
        alert("I'm loaded or reloaded.");

        // Target function of broadcasting via SignalR to all
        $.connection.adminHub.client.refresh = function() {
            window.location.reload(true); // forcing to forget about browser cache
        }

        // if the hub has been loaded, register click handler
        // if clicked refresh everywhere (without browser cache)
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $("#refreshButton").click(function () {
                alert("Button clicked!");
                $.connection.adminHub.server.reloadAll();
            })
        });
    });
})();
```

For the 3rd-party plugin I only include the AdminHub.cs in my assembly, as the rest is useless: the software I want to extend maps its own hub(s) successfully at the beginning, but not mine.

I appreciate any tricks or workarounds...

Comment: Please add some sample code and also the details of the error

Comment: I'll upload all the codes soon.